# Vimeo Embed code slow

Tags: iframe, vimeo

Does anyone know how I can speed up the load time on an embedded video, or at least force all frames to load last? Trying to optimize my site and finding that vimeo embeds are really holding me back. Advice you can give would be great. Here is the site I'm working on:

http://www.lcbcchurch.com

Comment: Did you resolve this, I'm having the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically add the embeds to the page via JavaScript once the whole page has loaded.

Comment: It doesnt matter if you load it via Ajax while observing visibiity. Google now loads everything.